# How to match special character using preg_match in php?

Tags: php, preg-match, php-5.3

I have this

```
$content1="W've have come across";
$content2="W've have come across all the oceans but still we don't find anything";
```

I have to strip out the content between "We've have come across"  and "anything"

What  kind of regex should I use when the content1,content2  can  change but they may contain apostrophe's or special characters?

How to use preg_match when you have special characters?

Comment: Will each `$content` always start with "We've have come across" and end with "anything"?  What is the expected output from `$content1` listed above?

Comment: Why don't you use `str_replace()` to replace known substrings?

Comment: The content doesn't start with "We've come across" It may contain special characters or may not..

str_replace - whether there is anyway to replace all the known special characters?because sometimes the content might be in UTF-8 encoding also :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) should help you, but as @Tomalak said -- why don't you want to use str_replace or something simple (not regexps)?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
function escape_regexp($regexp)
{
        $regex_chars = '^.[]$()|*+?{}' . "\\";
        $regexp = addcslashes($regexp, $regex_chars);

        return $regexp;
}
```

and then e.g. call:

```
preg_replace('/something' . escape_regexp($var1) . 
    'something else/', '', $string)
```

I didn't use preg_quote() because I wanted function for general regexp escaping, not just for PHP, but also for mysql. I wanted a different character set. I didn't want charactes < and > to be escaped - I didn't find reason for escaping them.

Comment: Whether we can use the same thing for preg_match also?

Comment: of course! I also used it for escaping the regexp for mysql! Also note that I didn't use preg_quote because the character set escaped by this function was slightly different. However my character set stems directly from PHP regexp documentation.

Comment: @Tomas, why dont' you use standard preg_quote ?

Comment: As I explained - because I use it for general regexp escaping, not just for PHP, but also for mysql. I wanted a different character set. I didn't want charactes < and > to be escaped - there's no reason to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Without regexp, I'd use this :

```
function weirdExtract($str, $start, $end){
    $posa = strripos($str, $start);
    $posb = strripos($str, $end);
    if($posa === false || $posb === false) return '';
    $startlen = strlen($start);
    return substr($str, $posa + $startlen, $posb - $startlen);
}
```

Used like this : http://codepad.viper-7.com/BJmEGG

strripos() can be changed with the appropriate function if case is important.